# Not able to CHEF bootstrap a windows EC2 instance, Winrm error

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, winrm

I am using CHEF 12 and trying to bootstrap an EC2 instance (Win server 2012 R2) from my workstation. However, I am getting the below error.

```
> Waiting for remote response before
> bootstrap.....................ERROR: No response received from remote
> node after 2.08 minutes, giving up. ERROR: Network Error: No
> connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
> it. - connect(2) (http://52.76.1.57:5985) Check your knife
> configuration and network settings
```

I have two CHEF servers (Hosted as well as on-premises); I have tried bootstraping the EC2 instance using each of these, but get the same result.

Chef bootstrap command issued via power-shell:

```
PS ~\chef-repo> knife bootstrap windows winrm 52.76.1.57 --winrm-user Administrator --winrm-password '******' --node-name node_145 --run-list 'recipe[ie::esc],recipe[install_iis]'
```

As far as I researched, it is because I am not able to establish a WINRM connection from my workstation to the Ec2 instance. I am however able to connect to another Win 2012 server within my office network and bootstrap successfully.

- have already logged in remotely to the EC2 instance and run winrm quickconfig from powershell.
- have set the Administrator password to a desired one.
- Have opened inbound firewall rule for WIndows remote management on ports 5985 and 5986
- Set up setcurity group and allowed inbound Custom TCP rule for ports 5985 and 5986 on AWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you took all the necessary steps for this, would it be possible that you are getting filtered by a firewall (e.g company firewall)?

fyi, I managed to bootstrap a machine with the following steps:

```
# configure winrm for using knife winrm
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
set-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\allowunencrypted $true
#turn off firewall
Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled False
```

EDIT: to sum up below comments, the problem was the company firewall that was blocking the traffic

Comment: Thanks!   These you did on the EC2 instance or on your company laptop?

Comment: I did this on EC2 instance, windows R2 2012. If the problem is between your laptop and your instance, you can try to bootstrap from another ec2 instance configured as a workstation? or, depending on your use case, a common practice is to bootstrap Chef from the userdata of the spawned instances.

Comment: I ran the winrm configs scripts and set the Administrator password using the user data file. I could even install chef-client using the user data file, however i will still at some point need to use knife winrm to run other recepies in the future from my workstation.

Comment: I suspect the firewall of your company to filter outgoing traffic. if yes, then you may ask to add some rules so that you can run knife, or use an ec2 instance as workstation

Comment: Thanks Tom! yes it was indeed the company firewall. I got them to open the firewall for an Elastic IP that I would be using and that was it. Winrm connections are now successful after opening the firewall for that particular IP by Enterprise IT.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 2012 R2 introcuced changes within WinRM security, which rendered some of old articles / readme examples explaining usage of `knife-ec` and `knife-windows` unusable.

This article http://blog.coderinserepeat.com/2015/07/15/chef-knife-ec2-and-knife-windows/ pretty much sums up how to deal with this in recent versions of knife plugins.